# Quartz device: plot is cutoff by default

Tags: r, plot, quartz-graphics

Does anyone have any insight as to why the plot region would be cut off by default using the Quartz device?

```
% R --vanilla
> plot(1,1)
```

gives me this;

[image]

The plot settings are normal

```
> par("mar")
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
```

and running `quartz.options(reset=TRUE)` doesn't seem to change anything.  What did I mess up??  *Note this is a not a problem using the X11 device.*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: does anything change when you resize the window

Comment: Ah, yes it does!  Once I change the window size the plot looks normal.  Is the default size too large, you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment by @rawr spurred me in the right direction...

The size of the device is too large relative to the screen resolution.  I used

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"), 
  function(...) grDevices::quartz.options(width = 6, height = 6))
```

in `~/.Rprofile` to reduce the defaults (from 7x7).